# JavaFX - Text is bigger when compiled than in SceneBuilder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have a problem in JavaFX. Text is bigger when I run program than in SceneBuilder.

Run program:
[JavaFX Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZvFc.png)
SceneBuilder:
[Window in SceneBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbmqn.png)

This is fxml file:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="450.0" prefHeight="200.0"prefWidth="450.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <GridPane layoutX="24.0" layoutY="14.0" prefWidth="406.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="60.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="180.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="85.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="85.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label text="Rozszerzenie" />
            <Label text="Główny katalog" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Katolog docelowy" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseMainDirectory" text="Przeszukaj" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseTargetDirectory" text="Przeszukaj" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Button>
            <TextField fx:id="mainDirectory" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <TextField fx:id="targetDirectory" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <AnchorPane fx:id="choiceDeck" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <children>
                  <CheckBox layoutY="6.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text=".jpg" />
                  <CheckBox layoutX="48.0" layoutY="6.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text=".jpeg" />
              <CheckBox layoutX="104.0" layoutY="6.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text=".gif" />
                  <CheckBox layoutX="150.0" layoutY="6.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text=".bmp" />
                  <CheckBox layoutY="30.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text=".png" />
                  <CheckBox layoutX="49.0" layoutY="30.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text=".tiff" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <Button layoutX="368.0" layoutY="161.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#confirm" text="Zatwierdź" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" />
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="161.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancel" text="Anuluj" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Please help me with this problem. In another PC it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font size/exact control size can differ between different JavaFX versions/OS. You shouldn't use absolute positions here. I recommend using a layout that chooses the positions of it's children based on their size instead. Suitable layouts would be `GridPane` (if you want to ensure the number of cells stays the same regardless of font size window size ect. and `ComboBox` should align horizontally) or `FlowPane` (if you want to place a bunch of `ComboBox`es similar to text and don't care about the horizontal alignment or the exact number of `ComboBox`es per row).

```xml
...
<FlowPane fx:id="choiceDeck" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
  <children>
      <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text=".jpg" />
      <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text=".jpeg" />
      <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text=".gif" />
      <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text=".bmp" />
      <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text=".png" />
      <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text=".tiff" />
   </children>
</FlowPane>
...
```

```xml
...
<GridPane fx:id="choiceDeck" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" hgap="3" vgap="5" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
  <children>
      <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text=".jpg" />
      <CheckBox GridPane.columnIndex="1" mnemonicParsing="false" text=".jpeg" />
      <CheckBox GridPane.columnIndex="2" mnemonicParsing="false" text=".gif" />
      <CheckBox GridPane.columnIndex="3" mnemonicParsing="false" text=".bmp" />
      <CheckBox GridPane.rowIndex="1" mnemonicParsing="false" text=".png" />
      <CheckBox GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" mnemonicParsing="false" text=".tiff" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I made a CSS style for app to set text size for all texts. It help me with this problem of JavaFX version. Also I used your tip about layouts.